# JUnit - Private method causing test to fail

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit4

This is the method I'm testing from the myClient class:

```
public FSDataInputStream getObj(String hName, Path p) throws IOException {

    if (p.toString().contains("?tkn=")) {
      checkToken(p);
      p = new Path(removeTkn(p.toString()));
    }

    String myKey = pathToKey(hName, p);
    FileStatus status = memoryCache.getStatus(p.toString());
    if (status == null) {
      status = getStatus(hName, p, "getObj");
    }
    if (status.isDirectory()) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Can't open " + path
  + " because it is a directory");
    }
    InputStream inputStream = new InputStream(bucket, myKey,
    status.getLen(), client, readAhead, inputPolicy);

    return new FSDataInputStream(inputStream);
}
```

This JUnit tests checks that an exception is thrown if the fileStatus is directory in method:

```
@Test
public void getDirectoryObjectTest() throws Exception {
  String host = "file://abc.def";
  Path p = new Path("file://abc.def/123.txt");
  when(memoryCache.getStatus(p.toString())).thenReturn(fileStatus);
  when(fileStatus.isDirectory()).thenReturn(true);
  exception.expect(FileNotFoundException.class);
  myClient.getObj(host, p);
}
```

It works as expected.

I now wish to do the same test but with path `file://abc.def/123.txt?tkn=xyz`. If I simply do this:

```
@Test
public void getDirectoryObjectTest2() throws Exception {
  String host = "file://abc.def";
  Path p = new Path("file://abc.def/123.txt?tkn=xyz");
  when(memoryCache.getStatus(p.toString())).thenReturn(fileStatus);
  when(fileStatus.isDirectory()).thenReturn(true);
  exception.expect(FileNotFoundException.class);
  myClient.getObj(host, p);
}
```

I get the following error:

> org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLInitializationException: class configured for SSLContext: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$TLSContext not a SSLContext
>       at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkSSLContext.getPreferredSSLContext(SdkSSLContext.java:37)
>       at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.getPreferredSocketFactory(ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.java:91)
>       at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.create(ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.java:65)
>       at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.create(ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.java:58)
>       at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheHttpClientFactory.create(ApacheHttpClientFactory.java:50)
>   ....

`checkToken()` is a private void method which creates an AmazonS3 client. For the purpose of this test I'm not concerned with it. Is there any way I can create some sort of mock which will allow the test to run?

**Edit**

adding `checkToken()`

```
private void checkToken(Path p) {
    String tkn = Utils.extractTkn(p);
    customTkn = new CustomTokenManager(tkn);
    creds = new BasicOAuthCredentials(customTkn, serviceInstanceID);

    cConf = new ClientConfiguration();
    credProvider = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(creds);

    clientBuilder = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
        .withClientConfiguration(cConf)
        .withPathStyleAccessEnabled(true)
        .withCredentials(cProvider);

    if (serviceUrl != null && !serviceUrl.equals(amazonDefaultEndpoint)) {
      EndpointConfiguration endpoint = new EndpointConfiguration(serviceUrl,
          Regions.DEFAULT_REGION.getName());
      clientBuilder.withEndpointConfiguration(endpoint);

    } else {
      clientBuilder.withRegion(Regions.DEFAULT_REGION);
    }
    myClient = clientBuilder.build();

}
```

**Update**

I've made an attempt at this but it's obviously not correct. I'm not sure how wrong I am though. Am I even on the right path?

I created mocks for `AmazonS3ClientBuilder`, `ClientConfiguration` and `AWSStaticCredentialsProvider`:

```
@Mock
AmazonS3ClientBuilder mClientBuilder;

@Mock
ClientConfiguration mClientConf;

@Mock
AWSStaticCredentialsProvider mCredsProvider;
```

I then amended my test as follows:

```
@Test
public void getDirectoryObjectTest2() throws Exception {
  String host = "file://abc.def";
  Path p = new Path("file://abc.def/123.txt?tkn=xyz");
  when(memoryCache.getStatus(p.toString())).thenReturn(fileStatus);
  when(fileStatus.isDirectory()).thenReturn(true);
  when(AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
      .withClientConfiguration(mClientConf)
      .withPathStyleAccessEnabled(true)
      .withCredentials(mCredsProvider)).thenReturn(mClientBuilder);
  exception.expect(FileNotFoundException.class);
  myClient.getObj(host, p);
}
```

I think part of the reason this isn't working is because whilst I've created the mocks, they don't actually have any value.

Also, when I run the test I get this:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Invoking the beforeTestMethod method on PowerMock test listener org.powermock.api.extension.listener.AnnotationEnabler@333d4a8c failed.
>       at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.PowerMockTestNotifierImpl.notifyBeforeTestMethod(PowerMockTestNotifierImpl.java:92)
>       at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:292)
>       at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
>       at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.access$100(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:59)
>       at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner$LastRuleTestExecutorStatement.evaluate(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:148)
>       at org.junit.rules.ExpectedException$ExpectedExceptionStatement.evaluate(ExpectedException.java:239)
>       at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:91)
>       at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)
>       at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
>       at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
>       at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
>       at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122)
>       at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:106)
>       at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
>       at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder
>       at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:447)
>       at org.mockito.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
>       at org.mockito.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:217)
>       at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:378)
>       at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:318)
>       at org.powermock.api.mockito.repackaged.ClassImposterizer.createProxyClass(ClassImposterizer.java:123)
>       at org.powermock.api.mockito.repackaged.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:57)
>       at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.createMethodInvocationControl(MockCreator.java:110)
>       at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.mock(MockCreator.java:58)
>       at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mock(PowerMockito.java:203)
>       at org.powermock.api.extension.listener.AnnotationEnabler.standardInject(AnnotationEnabler.java:106)
>       at org.powermock.api.extension.listener.AnnotationEnabler.beforeTestMethod(AnnotationEnabler.java:54)
>       at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.PowerMockTestNotifierImpl.notifyBeforeTestMethod(PowerMockTestNotifierImpl.java:90)
>       ... 24 more

The above error was actually getting thrown when I added only the below and ran the original version of `getDirectoryObjectTest2()` so its possibly some other issue:

```
@Mock
AmazonS3ClientBuilder mClientBuilder;
```

Is this correct?

**Update2**

I added `AmazonS3ClientBuilder` to the `@PrepareForTest` annotation.

```
@PrepareForTest({ObjectMetadata.class, COSInputPolicy.class, AmazonS3ClientBuilder.class})
```

Now I get this error:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
>   when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
>   For example:
>       when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);
>
> Also, this error might show up because:
>   1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
>      Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
>      Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
>   2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.
>
> at com.ibm.stocator.fs.cos.unittests.COSAPIClientTest.getDirectoryObjectWithTokenInPathTest(COSAPIClientTest.java:263)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
>       at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:89)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:97)
>       at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:294)
>       at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
>       at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.access$100(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:59)
>       at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner$LastRuleTestExecutorStatement.evaluate(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:148)
>       at org.junit.rules.ExpectedException$ExpectedExceptionStatement.evaluate(ExpectedException.java:239)
>       at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:91)
>       at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)
>       at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
>       at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
>       at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
>       at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122)
>       at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:106)
>       at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
>       at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

Is this purely because checkToken() is private or am I doing some thing else wrong?

Comment: Change your code so that you inject a `TokenChecker`, so that you can pass in a testing implementation for your tests, or a "real" implementation for production.

Comment: Obviously your problem is inside `checkToken()` which you did not show. However, a unittest should replace all dependencies with test doubles (stubs, fakes or mocks) which you did not so that your production code tries to access a real resource...

Comment: @TimothyTruckle, I added `checkToken()` to my question. So I need test doubles for everything in `checkToken()`, i.e. tkn, customTkn, creds, cConf, credProvider, client builder etc?

Comment: *"So I need test doubles for everything in checkToken(), i.e. tkn, customTkn, creds, cConf, credProvider, client builder etc?"* basically yes. You replace anything that contributes behavior not related to the current test and/or access to external resources. You do not mock *Data Transfer Objects* (DTOs) or other classes that contribute *directly* to the tested behavior. From your error message I'd say that you should (at least) pass in the result of `AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()` via *dependency injection* and replace it with a test double.

Comment: You are trying to inject mocks to method local variables. With Mockito it will not work. Not sure if PowerMockito can do it with AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard() static method. Also, seems that checkToken it is not doing the thing that name implies. I assume, it resets the value of myClient member with a new AmazonS3 client if authentication is successful.